# Diferentes timezones em uma aplicação com PostgreSQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Temos um sistema que atende diversos centros de distribuição. Um centro de distribuição é um local físico que pode estar localizado em qualquer parte do país. Um mesmo cliente pode ter diversos centros. Nosso sistema pode atuar em todos esses centros. Como agora estamos expandindo para mais locais, vamos ter que enfrentar o problema de diferentes timezones. Um mesmo cliente pode, ainda, ter centros com diferentes timezones.

Diversos eventos podem ser criados e armazenados (com data e hora) utilizando nosso sistema nos centros de um cliente. O comportamento ideal para diferentes timezones em um mesmo cliente é o seguinte:

Dado que um evento acontece em um centro que está no timezone A, ao meio dia. Se
um supervisor de um centro que se encontra no timezone B for olhar a data/hora
desse evento, ele deve visualizar essa data/hora formatados respeitando o timezone
onde o evento ocorreu (inclusive com o horário de verão do local do evento em conta, se houver). Isso porque o que importa é saber se um evento foi localmente (no timezone onde foi feito) realizado ao meio dia (ou qualquer outro horário de exemplo). Para o supervisor, não é importante saber que ao meio dia quando o evento foi feito era 14h onde ele estava.

Nós utilizamos PostgreSQL como nosso banco de dados e eu vi que existem dois tipos
de timestamps para se salvar data/hora. Um deles é o `TIMESTAMP` e o outro é o `TIMESTAMPTZ`.
Todo o nosso banco de dados utiliza apenas o tipo `TIMESTAMP`.

Um outro cenário que pode ser bem raro de acontecer mas ainda sim é possível, é o caso de um centro ser trocado geograficamente de lugar, com isso impactando na mudança de seu timezone.

Segundo minhas pesquisas, o mais correto a se fazer parece ser salvar o timezone que cada centro tem em uma coluna na tabela `CENTRO_DISTRIBUICAO`. Trocar todos os tipos `TIMESTAMP` em nosso banco para `TIMESTAMPTZ` e no momento de cada insert de algo que salve data/hora utilizar o timezone do centro que está inserindo os dados para salvar junto o offset do timezone (visto que o campo `TIMESTAMPTZ` não salva o timezone em si, mas apenas o offset).

Minha dúvida é saber se esse é mesmo o melhor caminho e o jeito certo de se lidar com esses diferentes timezones. Como nunca implementei nada que precisasse desse suporte, não sei dizer.

Se eu resolver seguir essa abordagem, será preciso alterar o tipo de todas as colunas no banco de `TIMESTAMP` para `TIMESTAMPTZ`. Também será preciso recriar todas as views que dependem dessas colunas, pois os tipos estão sendo alterados. Além disso, será preciso alterar todas as queries que lidam com essas colunas para aplicarem o timezone do centro usando `AT TIMEZONE`.

O banco tem atualmente como timezone `America/Sao_Paulo` e meu receio é o de acabar fazendo algo errado ao realizar a troca das colunas para `TIMESTAMPTZ`. Esse cast pode acabar com a consistência dos timestamps já armazenados? Qual o jeito correto de fazer isso, devo primeiro realizar o cast ou primeiro alterar o timezone do banco para `UTC`?

A solução que descrevi é a melhor forma de lidar com o problema?

Essa abordagem também lida corretamente com o horário de verão de cada lugar?

Informações extras: nosso servidor é java (jersey) e o front é tanto mobile quanto web.

Comment: Já passei por um problema parecido, segui [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537106/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-store-time-in-utc-or-is-this-the-case-where-storing), e [esta aqui tambem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666836/date-time-conversion-from-users-local-time-to-utc-on-website/5667869#5667869)

Comment: Agradeço pelas sugestões de posts. Já havia consultado um deles. Infezlimente, não ajudaram muito no meu caso.

Answer (score 8):

Você pode alterar a variavél de ambiente `TIMEZONE` quando a aplicação (cliente) se conectar ao banco de dados.

A ideia aqui é: Cada cliente seria responsável por ajustar seu *timezone*, e o servidor permaneceria com seu *timezone* padrão, por exemplo:

```
SET TIMEZONE TO 'Brazil/Acre';
SELECT NOW(); -- Horário oficial do Acre

SET TIMEZONE TO 'America/Sao_Paulo';
SELECT NOW(); -- Horário oficial de Brasília/São Paulo

SET TIMEZONE TO 'Brazil/DeNoronha';
SELECT NOW(); -- Horário oficial de Fernando de Noronha

SET TIMEZONE TO 'UTC';
SELECT NOW(); -- Universal Time Coordinated

SET TIMEZONE TO 'GMT';
SELECT NOW(); -- Greenwich Mean Time
```

Para verificar o `TIMEZONE` configurado no cliente:

```
SHOW TIMEZONE;
```

Segue um exemplo prático ilustrando a ideia:

1) Criação de uma tabela teste `tb_foobar` contendo um campo do tipo `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`:

```
CREATE TABLE public.tb_foobar
(
    id BIGINT, 
    datahora TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);
```

2) Cada Centro de Distribuição faz o `INSERT` usando seu respectivo `TIMEZONE`:

```
-- CENTRO DE DISTRIBUICAO #1
SET TIMEZONE TO 'Brazil/Acre';
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, datahora ) VALUES ( 1, now() );

-- CENTRO DE DISTRIBUICAO #2
SET TIMEZONE TO 'America/Sao_Paulo';
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, datahora ) VALUES ( 2, now() );

-- CENTRO DE DISTRIBUICAO #3
SET TIMEZONE TO 'Brazil/DeNoronha';
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, datahora ) VALUES ( 3, now() );

-- CENTRO DE DISTRIBUICAO #4
SET TIMEZONE TO 'UTC';
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, datahora ) VALUES ( 4, now() );

-- CENTRO DE DISTRIBUICAO #5
SET TIMEZONE TO 'GMT';
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, datahora ) VALUES ( 5, now() );
```

3) O mesmo se aplica na geração dos relatórios, cada centro de distribuição possui um `TIMEZONE` configurado:

São Paulo:

```
-- GERACAO DE RELATORIO NO CENTRO DE DISTRIBUCAO #2
SET TIMEZONE TO 'America/Sao_Paulo';
SELECT * FROM tb_foobar ORDER BY id;
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Greenwich:

```
-- GERACAO DE RELATORIO NO CENTRO DE DISTRIBUCAO #5
SET TIMEZONE TO 'GMT';
SELECT * FROM tb_foobar ORDER BY id;
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em um primeiro momento essa parece uma boa abordagem. Mas no primeiro caso em que uma query lidar com dados de mais de um centro de distribuição que tenham timezones diferentes (na geração de relatórios, por exemplo) ela não vai funcionar.

Comment: @Luiz: EDIT - Incluido um exemplo prático como prova de funcionamento.